# Can I disable people sharing Google Photos with me?

Tags: gmail, google-photos

I have a good Gmail id and probably because of that I get ton of emails people sharing their photos with me (to my Gmail account).

Is there way I can disable this so nobody can share their pics with me?

Please see the attached, these are the requests I get in sharing when I open google photos. Also one other weird issue is that I can leave these shares except the first one. No menu or (...) there when I hover the mouse over it. How can I leave that one?

[image]

Comment: Out of interest, do you think they are intentionally sharing their photos with you, because your Gmail address is simple?

Comment: @ahorn Good question that I haven't really understood. They probably intentionally share it but also I get so much unwanted mail from people that has *same* name as my first name but its not marketing emails, many times email has no body. I am like why would anyone send email to themselves if it was a name mistake? It makes no sense, pretty crazy.